# How can I expire the session when the user doesn't work with website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello, I created a web site application with asp.net 4.5 and asp.net membership. I want user session to be expire if the user doesn't work with site (like Facebook).

I have set the timeout in `web.config` for the session but this time gets finished (times out), either if user works or doesn't work. Is there something I'm missing?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Pages/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="1"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to know?

Comment: i want session expired when user don't work with site,
such as facebook(in facebook when you work with site,session don't expired,but if facebook page is open in a few minutes and user don't any action user will be logout), i want do it

Comment: forms auth timeout is different from session timeout, please explain.

Comment: You have declared `sliding experience` ,this will do, according to your web config. ,If a user is idle for one minute his session will be expired but `slidingexpiration` will make this session to continue as long as user is active on site. If i am missing something please let me know.

Comment: i think there is something else which is causing problem, can you post your code where you are performing authentication.

Answer (score 0):

While setting the forms auth cookie you need to set an expiry time for the cookie and create a http module in your application where you check the auth cookie in the request headers and if its not present you logout the user and redirect to the login page. And if the cookie exists just reset the expiry time for the cookie in the response.

Comment: thank's for your answer,but it's possible show me with code or example?

Comment: This post here might help you out. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902194/asp-net-forms-authentication-timeout

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966150/save-variable-when-session-end-event-triggers-in-global-asax/18966774#18966774). This is an answered that I'm currently help with another user. This should show you how to make the session start once the user logs in.

Edit: Not sure why the downvote, but here is code then.

Change the timeouts on each of the forms authentication and sessionState like below.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Dashboard.aspx" timeout="60"/>
    </authentication>
    <sessionState timeout="60" mode="InProc" cookieless="false" />
```

Then, put this into your Site.Master.cs under the page load.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Handle the session timeout 
                string sessionExpiredUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/DealLog/Account/SessionExpired.aspx";
                StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
                script.Append("function expireSession(){ \n");
                script.Append(string.Format(" window.location = '{0}';\n", sessionExpiredUrl));
                script.Append("} \n");
                script.Append(string.Format("setTimeout('expireSession()', {0}); \n", this.Session.Timeout * 60000)); // Convert minutes to milliseconds 
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "expirescript", script.ToString(), true);
            }
```

The session will only expire if the user is authenticated. The user logs in, becomes inactive, and then session times out. Once it times out, goes to an SessionExpired page. On the session expired page, place

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

in the page load so it signs out the user. Then you can set up a redirect from there. The Authentication and SessionState timeouts are both in minutes. 60 = 1 hour.

Edit 2: It looks like the user of the question that was linked in my answer was deleted by the user. Sorry for that. Hope this helps though.